# Python, infinite floats?

Tags: python, function, decimal

**What I wanted to do:**

Paradox: Suppose Peter Parker were running to catch a bus. To reach it, he’d first need to get halfway there. Before that, he’d need to get a quarter of the way there……before a quarter, an eighth; before an eighth, a 16th; and so on. Since the distance can be halved infinitely, he’d be trying to complete an infinite number of tasks… WHICH WOULD BE LOGICALLY IMPOSSIBLE!

I tried to to resolve this paradox using Python

I have some questions:
How can I get a number to have no limitations with decimals? *Python limits the numbers of decimals, I think to 12, How to make that number infinite?*

*Aparrently there is no way to make the float decimals infinite, the closest I could get was using this*

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

Is this the correct way of asking the user for an input in numbers?
*Code modified*

```
from decimal import Decimal
def infinite_loop():
    x = 0;
    number = Decimal(raw_input())
    while x != number:
        x = x + number
        number = number/2
        print x
infinite_loop()
```

Comment: might help: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @Juanvulcano: What are you trying to do?  If you all you wanted is to grab a number from the user, a simple `number = float(raw_input())` would've sufficed.

Comment: Also why is it taking in a variable 'lol' if you are never using it that variable?

Comment: @CyanogenCX Python functions need an argument to work, you don't necessary need to call it.

Comment: @Juanvulcano No, they don't. You can define functions of zero arguments.

Comment: @senshin How can I define a function with no argument at all? I did not knew that

Comment: @Juanvulcano `def foo():` instead of `def foo(arg1, arg2):`. If you haven't read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/), you should do that.

Comment: @Juanvulcano Dude, no, it isn't new in Python 3. Zero-argument functions have been in Python since literally version 1.0. You should _really_ learn about the language before coming here and asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is impossible. There are no "infinite precision" floating point values in the real world of finite computing systems. If there were, a single floating point value could consume all of the system's resources. `pi * d`? Ooops!! `pi` is infinite. There goes the system!

What you can do, however, is get *arbitrary* precision decimal values. They're still finite, but you can choose how much precision you want (and are willing to pay for). E.g.:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal('1.' + '0' * 200)
>>> x
Decimal('1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
```

Now you have 200 digits of precision. Not enough? Go 400. 800. However many you like. As long as that's a finite, practical value.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the question I wanted to get answered.

Comment: Just be careful with concepts like "precision," "significant digits," and how much information you really have to represent. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) explain how to use `Decimal`s. It's intoxicating to think you can represent values with hyper-precision, but most data sources aren't precise enough to really need it, and the bulk of scientific and technical computing can be done within the (admittedly imprecise) realm of double-precision floating point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "infinite" precision (e.g. a decimal number that be extended as far as you have memory for), either use Python's builtin module [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) or for more heavy computation, [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/):

```
import mpmath as mp
mp.mp.dps = 100
print mp.sqrt(mp.mpf(2))

>> 1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573
```